# VS Code - change color of a text of a particular word in text editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VS Code to edit SQL.

To ensure that I am very very careful with our production database I was scratching my head to try to find a way so that whenever a `.sql` file is open in the editor, and the word `WHProduction` is written, it will be formatted either with a background color or the text can be say red colored.

Is this possible in VS Code either out-of-the-box in the settings.json or via an extension?

Comment: See this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight

Comment: @Zakk nice one - I'll delete this post as it is already answered!

Comment: Don't delete it. Just leave it as it is. Deleting posts will affect your reputation negatively.